# Concept for smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Given a class template like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    T data;
};
```

How may one determine whether `T` is a smart pointer such as `std::shared_ptr<T_underlying>` using C++20 concepts?

I want to add functionality to `foo<T>` based on this criteria. For example, Instead of using SFINAE, I'd like to use the new concept system.

I want to achieve something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    T data;

    void func()
    requires is_shared_ptr_v<T>
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Are there existing concepts for this in the STL? If not, I assume I can write a concept for `std::shared_ptr`, one for `std::unique_ptr` and so on and then tie them together with logical or in a general `is_smart_pointer` concept?

Comment: Think about how to do this with SFINAE, and simply translate it directly into a concept. With SFINAE you simply specialize and verify that the type is an instance of shared_ptr and unique_ptr. You simply do the same thing with a concept, so which part of this is unclear to you?

Comment: How do you define smart pointer in a way that differentiates from `T*` and `optional<T>`?

Comment: You already have the concept part of your code in the example. All that's left is to write the `is_shared_ptr_v` trait, which you would do in the same way it's been done since c++11.

Comment: Which semantics of `T` are relevant for you? Get that nailed down, then test for it as much as feasible, and finally convert to a `concept`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might first create a traits to detect if type is a `std::shared_ptr` (way depends if you want to consider inheritance or not).

And then use the traits to build a concept:

```
template <typename T> struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T> concept IsSharedPtr = is_shared_ptr<T>::value;
```

or

```
template <typename T>
std::true_type inherit_from_shared_ptr_impl(const std::shared_ptr<T>*);
std::false_type inherit_from_shared_ptr_impl(...);

template <typename T>
using inherit_from_shared_ptr =
    decltype(inherit_from_shared_ptr_impl(std::declval<T*>()));

template <typename T> concept InheritFromSharedPtr = inherit_from_shared_ptr<T>::value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Write "is pointer like".  Has unary dereference, explicit cast to bool, and is either a pointer or has an operator arrow.  Maybe that (for non pointers) get returns the same type as operator arrow.

Then state that a smart pointer is a pointer like thing that isn't a pointer.

Note that some iterators are smart pointers under this rule.

If you want an "owning" pointer you have to have a manual trait; there is no way to tell that other than semantically.